# Problem in executing single-linked-list in c without using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, linked-list, structure

I am writing the program for single-linked-list in 'c' without using dynamic memory allocation. But it is going into infinite loop.  The whole program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct SingleLinkedList
{
    int data;
    struct SingleLinkedList* next;
};

typedef struct SingleLinkedList sll;

void insertAtStart(sll** head, int data)
{
    sll newNode = { data, NULL };
    newNode.data = data;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = &newNode;
        return;
    }
    newNode.next = *head;
    *head = &newNode;
}

void insertAtEnd(sll** head, int data)
{
    sll newNode = { data, NULL };
    newNode.data = data;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = &newNode;
        return;
    }
    sll* node = *head;
    while (node -> next != NULL)
    {
        node = node -> next;
    }
    node -> next = &newNode;
}

void insertAfterNode(sll **head, int data)
{
    int nodeNum, count = 1;
    printf("\nEnter the node number to insert after: ");
    scanf("%d", &nodeNum);
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe List is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    sll *prevNode = *head;
    while (count < nodeNum && prevNode -> next != NULL)
    {
        prevNode = prevNode -> next;
        count++;
    }
    if (count < nodeNum)
    {
        printf("\nThere are only %d nodes in the list\n", count);
        return;
    }

    sll newNode = { data, NULL };
    newNode.next = prevNode -> next;
    prevNode -> next = &newNode;
}

int choiceSelection()
{
    int choice;
    printf("\nSelect an Option:\n");
    printf("1. Insert At Beginning\n");
    printf("2. Insert At Last\n");
    printf("3. Insert After Certain Node\n");
    printf("4. Print all nodes\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}

int dataEntry()
{
    int data;
    printf("\nEnter the data: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    return data;
}

void print(sll* node)
{
    int count = 1;
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n----------------%d----------------\n", count);
        printf("Data: %d", node -> data);
        printf("\tAddress: %p", node);
        printf("\tNext: %p\n", node -> next);
        node = node -> next;
        count++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    sll *head = NULL;
    enum option {
        InsertAtStart = 1,
        InsertAtEnd = 2,
        InsertAfterNode = 3,
        Print = 4,
        Exit = 5,
    } choice;

    while (choice != Exit)
    {
        choice = choiceSelection();
        switch (choice)
        {
            case InsertAtStart:
                insertAtStart(&head, dataEntry());
                break;
            case InsertAtEnd:
                insertAtEnd(&head, dataEntry());
                break;
            case InsertAfterNode:
                insertAfterNode(&head, dataEntry());
                break;
            case Print:
                print(head);
                break;
            case Exit:
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nIncorrect Choice..Please choose among 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nExiting!");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Select an Option:
1. Insert At Beginning
2. Insert At Last
3. Insert After Certain Node
4. Print all nodes
5. Exit
1

Enter the data: 2

Select an Option:
1. Insert At Beginning
2. Insert At Last
3. Insert After Certain Node
4. Print all nodes
5. Exit
4

----------------1----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------2----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------3----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------4----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------5----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------6----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------7----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------8----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------9----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------10----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------11----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0

----------------12----------------
Data: 0 Address: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0 Next: 0x7ffe2e94c0c0
--------^C
```

> It needed to be terminated manually.
>   Can someone tell me where the problem lies? Or is it not possible without using dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: It always behooves you to develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. Much of this code is irrelevant to the problem of constructing a linked list; hard-code some values, try building a list of, say, two elements, and see what happens.

Comment: `choice` is not initialized in the beginning. Your while loop is working with undefined behavior.

Comment: The `insertAtStart()` function tries to embed a pointer to a local variable in the list; that is a recipe for disaster.  You'll need a (statically) allocated array of structures from which you can allocate entries on demand.

Comment: Just for clarification: A local variable stops existing once the function returns. Therefore, all pointers to these local variables become [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) once the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible without dynamic allocation of some kind. If you don't want to use `malloc`, you could use your own implementation of an allocation arena.

But you cannot use dangling pointers, which is what your implementation does.

```
void insertAtStart(sll** head, int data)
{
    sll newNode = { data, NULL };
```

`newNode` is a variable with *automatic* storage duration, which means that it exists only until the function in which it is declared returns (or is otherwise exited).

```
    newNode.data = data;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = &newNode;
```

So now `*head` points to an object with automatic storage duration. But look what happens next:

```
        return;
```

As soon as that `return` executes, `insertAtStart` terminates and the lifetimes of all of its local variables, including `newNode` come to a sudden end. And when the lifetime of an object finishes, so does the usability of a pointer to that object.

```
    }
    newNode.next = *head;
    *head = &newNode;
}
```

---

I should note that although there are rules against what you are doing here, nothing actually tries to enforce them. Things just fail in mysterious ways.

Saying that the object's lifetime ends doesn't mean that the memory in which the object was stored ceases to exist. Your computer doesn't come equipped with little nanorobots which can build and disassemble physical memory. What it means is that the memory no longer contains that object, and might (will) be reused for some other purpose.

Similarly, although the C standard is clear that a pointer to the terminated object ceases to be usable ("The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to… reaches the end of its lifetime."), nothing actually stops you from trying to use the pointer; the problem is that it might point at a different object placed in the same memory. And that's what's going on here: the result is that your linked list ends up being a circular list of garbage.

Comment: Again, if i don't want to use use malloc, can using **static** be a good choice anyway, as the object's lifetime won't end then??

Comment: @Abinav: That would get you precisely one object with unlimited lifetime. But one presumes that your linked list consists of more than one node. If you used a `static` node, you would replace the current Undefined Behaviour with a program which reliably produced an infinite loop :-).

Comment: @Abinav: If you're going to program in C, you need to make `malloc` your friend. In fact, `malloc` is omnipresent in pretty well every other programming language you might use; it's just that it is called automatically so you don't notice it.